# How to load one helper function in all the controller functions without calling it everytime in all the functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add these helper function in all the controller functions

```
// this is my helper file custom_helper.php

// $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form', 'custom_helper');

function notifications()
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('custom_model');
    $select = "id, name";
    $tableName = "users";
    $whereCondition = "created_at = CURDATE()";
    $result = $CI->custom_model
                     ->FetchWithSelect($select,$tableName,$whereCondition);       
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create helper file in application/helper folder: xyz_helper.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    function notifications() 
    {
        $CI = get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('custom_model');
        $select = "id, name";
        $tableName = "users";
        $whereCondition = "created_at = CURDATE()";
        $result = $CI->custom_model
                     ->FetchWithSelect($select,$tableName,$whereCondition);       
        return $result;
    }
```

then open application/config/autoload.php file : add this

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file','form','xyz');
```

Also you don't need to put "custom_helper" in $autoload['helper'], just put "custom" and file in application/helper/custom_helper.php

Answer (score 1):

In /application/config/autoload.php change:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

to

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html', 'url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller probably extends a Codeigniter controller class. So, what you want is another class that extends it:

```
<?php

class Basecontroller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function notifications()
    {
        $CI = get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('custom_model');
        $select = "id, name";
        $tableName = "users";
        $whereCondition = "created_at = CURDATE()";
        $result = $CI->custom_model
                     ->FetchWithSelect($select,$tableName,$whereCondition);       
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then in all your controllers, extend that class!

```
<?php

class Home extends Basecontroller
{
    public function someActionOrOther()
    {
        $this->notifications(); // now works
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class naming is wrong in CI only first letter should be upper case ONLY in CI 3 > explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Indeed, I'm not a CI guy, but I know how to extend a class!

Comment: bt how to do these in CI

Comment: what is your controller extending?

Comment: class Home extends CI_Controller

Comment: Ok I edited my code snippets. If all your controllers including Home extend Basecontroller, which extends CI_Controller, then it'll work. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks.. this is a working solution.. bt i m looking for some optimisation ... in this way i have to call function notifications() in all the functions to access

Comment: You want it to run automatically? Maybe stick it in the `__construct()` method? (remember to also call `parent::__construct()`!

Comment: No? What's happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154128/discussion-between-satish51-and-delboy1978uk).

Answer (score 0):

By calling the helper function in the constructor of  every controller i dont think the helper function then needed to be called in every controller functions